# sorting the parent on basis of total flag count of his children

Tags: flags

I have a problem in getting the total flag count of all children belong to a parent. so that on basis of it i can sort to the parent.i have 2 parent A and B, and each parent has own children. like:

Parent A:-
child1 flag count=3

child2 flag count=0

child3 flag count=1

Parent B:-

child1 flag count=4

child2 flag count=1

child3 flag count=2

child4 flag count=0

So flag count of all children in parent B is greater. so in sorting, parent B should come first (because has 7 flag count in child node) then Parent A (flag count of all child nodes is 4)...

How can i get result

Comment: Did'n http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87547/adding-all-children-node-flag-count-to-sort-parent help you?